# NotifyListeners in Provider Pattern in MVC+S Design

Tags: flutter

I m developing a Flutter APP in MVC+S Design. Also I use the Providers with Notifylisteners but often I got the Message `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

What is the Best practice of using Providers and Notfylisteners to avoid this problem ?

My Code looks like:

```
Class Test() {

String? testA
String? testB


FunctionA async() {
... 
testA = 'TestA';
notfifyListeners() };



FunctionB async() {
... 
testB = 'TestB';
notfifyListeners();

}
```

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
.
.
. 
class TestState extends State<Test> {
 @override
 voide iniState() {
  locator<TestController>().FunctionA();
  locator<TestController>().FunctionB();
  super.initState();
 }

}

.
.
.

}
```

Comment: User `Future Builder` to wait for data loading from server. and listener will work once the build method complete its execution.

Answer (score 2):

the reason you're getting the exception is that you're updating the state when the widget is attempting to build.

The easiest way to avoid this is using `addPostFrameCallback` to ensure the state is updated after the initial build(it's very important):

```
class TestState extends State<Test> {
 @override
 voide iniState() {
   WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp){
      locator<TestController>().FunctionA();
      locator<TestController>().FunctionB();
    });
  super.initState();
 }

}
```

be careful to use `addPostFrameCallback` in your `dispose` method when you want to use a function that has `notfifyListeners()`.

Happy coding....

Answer (score 1):

You need waiting for build was completed:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      locator<TestController>().FunctionA();
      locator<TestController>().FunctionB();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not call provider in **initState** as at this moment your builder is still in the progress and there is no **BuildContext** available,

to avoid this many coders use **Future Delay** with **mounted** to check if BuildContext is ready or not in **initState**.

But **FutureBuilder** widget is the right option when you deal with future data.
this will automatically build the widget when data is available you do not need to check for **mounted**.

Comment: This works as long as there is only one Future for a declared Variable. i.E. you want to load data from the local storage and change it when the result from the API recieved than this soloution doesnt work. In this case I will use the soloution of @vanosidor . Thanks to all of you for the answers. This helped me a lot.